# Joomla external links

Tags: php, joomla

[Here](http://ustudy.kz/vk/widget/test.php) is my simple php page in which i have links to the Joomla article, but all links are broken, it returns "file not found". I understand, that these external links don't work because they indicate internal pages of Joomla(1.5). How should I configure them so they will start to work?

p.s.: please, forgive me for my terrible English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the settings of the page to public. you can do it by using joomla options.
then get the URI try with that. Should work.

edit : also you might have to define the access levels. Follow this [link as guide](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-feb-2012/item/639-Joomla-ACL-Access-Levels?tmpl=component&print=1).

Comment: but my page is not Joomla page, it's just a php-page which contains links to Joomla pages. Can you show the way to get info from Joomla articles?thanks for any given help.

Comment: Have I got this correctly ?
your normal php page is: http://ustudy.kz/vk/widget/test.php and 
your joomla page is: http://ustudy.kz/vk/widget/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=86&test=1
 If it is true what I have given above is still valid. Is that the other way around ??

Comment: yes, i have joomla article numbered 86, and all links on test.php indicates to this article

Comment: So you should be just fine. Just follow the instruction I gave.